# How to find equivalent components?

Tags: components

Vendor doesn't have the following components:

MOSFETs:
   P-channel MOSFET    IRF9Z34N
   N-channel MOSFET   IRLZ24N
   N-channel MOSFET   2N7000
   N-channel MOSFET   IRFZ46N

Diode:          1N5818
OpAmp:      MC34074P

Is there a quick way to find out equivalent components?

Comment: You can always look at other vendors that might have it. jameco seems to have some of these in stock.

Comment: I get the impression people use the parametric search features of the major vendors web-sites.

Comment: Assuming you are a hobbyist or experimenter looking for small volumes from some local electronic components shop: Any vendor who does not have a 2n7000 is definitely not a vendor you want to be buying components from. I deal with really small and inexpensive components shops all the time, and the 2n7000 is sold at every single one of them. Where is this vendor based?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking this question, best thing is FIRST look for other vendors. Substitutions can be tricky if you aren't really sure WHICH parameters a circuit relies upon.

Try http://www.findchips.com/ - They're excellent for this !

Hope that helps,
Best Regards, Dave

Answer (score 0):

Find a vendor who specializes and/or is knowledgeable in the specific area in which you are using such components. For example if it is just some hobby type circuit it is possible that virtually any little diode might be OK as a sub for  1N5158. Its a general thing really (not just for electronics) - find a vendor who is relevant to your work/hobby and they will help you out with equivalents, substitutions. I also find google "equivalent to 2Nxxxxx" usually comes up with useful ideas. Finally buy  data/equivalents books (not all useful info is on the www !) many 100s have been published (I have a whole bookcase full of them !!!). Then it is "quick" if the info is in your own library. Available from the usual auction and book selling sites.

Comment: im a bit disappointed nobody gave me even one of these components equivalent. it means it is tough

Comment: Tell us what you are building or give us a link to article/circuit & we can advise if these are "critical" application(s) where equivalents need to be considered carefully or bog standard where any near stuff will do. I will do it myself if its within my area of knowledge.

Comment: im trying to make a simple function generator and some other circuits to gain some experience. i was following this tutorial but couldnt find the components i was looking. here is the link: http://www.homofaciens.de/technics-base-circuits-function-generator_en_navion.htm